# SQL sumarize first x rows

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql-9.0

I have a SQL result like this:

```
 name | points
------+-------
 Joe  | 2
 Joe  | 5
 Joe  | 4
 Joe  | 1
```

Each row represents how many points Joe received per event.

Joe has some basic budget, let's say $100.

What I need to do now is to add a field, which will represent actual budget value, when one point means $10 addition. Something like history of budget growth.

The result should look like this:

```
 name | points | budget
------+--------+-------
 Joe  | 2      | 120
 Joe  | 5      | 170
 Joe  | 4      | 210
 Joe  | 1      | 220
```

Usage of a variable seems like the best solution to me, but PostgreSQL is not much friendly with it, so I'm looking for a solution using sumarization of first x rows of the result to get actual points sum since the beginning.

Do you have any idea how to do this without subselecting in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, 
       points,
       100 + sum(points * 10) over (partition by name order by some_timestamp_column) as budget
from the_table
order by some_timestamp_column
```

You **have** to have a column that defines a stable sort order over the rows in order to use this.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This Postgre-specific solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mEan: that is *not* Postgres specific. That is standard ANSI SQL and works in all modern DBMS. (Btw: it's Postgres or PostgreSQL, **never** Postgre)

Comment: Oh, OK. I probably misunderstood what Samuel Neff wrote, I thought this soulution cannot be used cross-database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I don't think this works in MySQL.  It definitely doesn't work in SQLite.

Comment: @SamuelNeff: I never claimed it would work on MySQL or SQLite. I wrote "modern" DBMS - MySQL stopped keeping up with state-of-the-art SQL features somewhere in the 90s (after adding partial support for foreign keys)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, both MySQL and SQLite are heavily used today and continue to be very popular.  "modern" is definitely up to interpretation.  I wouldn't call them less modern because they don't support this particular feature.

Comment: @SamuelNeff: it's not only that feature that makes MySQL "not modern" (at least in my eyes). There are plenty of others which MySQL simply doesn't offer. Popular doesn't mean "good" or "modern"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, technical answers are easier understood when opinions are not used to identify where the answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres supports this type of accumulation using an `OVER` clause, like this:

```
SELECT name, points, SUM(points * 10) OVER (ORDER BY .. order field ..)
FROM .. table ..
GROUP BY .. unique field ..
```

A cross-database alternative without a sub-select would be to add this column in your host language (php, java, whatever) and not do it in the database.

Comment: Using window functions **is** a cross-DBMS solution. They are defined by the SQL standard (back in 2003) and every modern DBMS supports them.